# PHP Google Adwords API get campaigns

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google adwords API to connect with adwords and list all the campaingns. I am connecting with OAuth to the Adwords account and become an access_token and an refresh_token, which I am saving into the DB.

Now I am trying to make this example:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201802/BasicOperations/GetCampaigns.php

But my access_token and my refresh_token are in the database and all the API OAuth2 credentials are in one configuration array.

How to query hte google adwords service with this credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth2TokenBuilder class referred to in line 81 of your example and copied below has several methods that'll let you set parameters instead of reading them from the config file.

```
$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();
```

The fromFile method will read parameters from the config file. Your new code might look something like this:

```
$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->withClientId(your oauth2 client id here)
        ->withClientSecret(your oauth2 client secret here)
        ->withRefreshToken(your stored refresh token here)
        ->build();
```

High level overview of some other issues with the Google AdWords API here:
https://pete-bowen.com/how-to-use-the-google-adwords-api-to-automate-adwords

Comment: Thanks, that helped me! Cheers Nik :)